# How to use Switch...Case in generic type parameter in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a class where I am using `Generic Type Parameter` to dynamically use it. Right now, I am using `if..else` which works fine with my custom classes. I was wondering if I can use `switch..case` here.

If data types are `decimal` or `int` then I can use `TypeCode` like this.

```
switch (Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(T)))
{
    case TypeCode.Int32:
       break;
    case TypeCode.Decimal:
       break;
}
```

But I have custom classes which I created and I want to use them. Below code works and trying to use `switch..case` if possible.

**My Code:**

```
void LogError<T>(T response, string orderId)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(QuoteResponse))
    {
        var quoteResponse = response as QuoteResponse;

        //Do something
    }
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(CommitResponse))
    {
        var commitResponse = response as CommitResponse;

        //Do something
    }
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(CancelResponse))
    {
        var cancelResponse = response as CancelResponse;

        //Do something
    }
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(StatusResponse))
    {
        var statusResponse = response as StatusResponse;

        //Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: If your method is not generic after all, why even make it generic? Just have four overloads.

Comment: Why shouldn’t it work? Have you tried it?

Comment: C# 7.0 or above supports pattern matching in switch case statements. See details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#using-pattern-matching-switch-statements

Comment: @Matt.G - please turn your comment into an answer. All the existing answers do NOT answer the question (although they make very valid points) This is an X-Y problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Matt.G This is helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to know what the type of `T` is, you probably aren't using generics properly.  Ask yourself: what happens if someone uses a `T` that you haven't accounted for?

It seems like what you need is to have a base class `Response` and then derive the other classes from it, then you can create a factory method which produces the appropriate instances of the derived classes depending on some logic.

Comment: Or implement a virtual method in the base Response class; override the method in the child classes to get the correct behaviour for that class. Basic o-o polymorphism.

Comment: @rory.ap This makes sense.

Comment: This may make sense in this specific case, but the real answer is that c# (probably even .NET itself) lacks a mechanism that allows for generics type specialization, where you could make overloads based on specific type parameters so it can make use of better code for some of them, and a default for everything else. If you look at Microsoft's own Linq code you will notice how they really wished they had a way to specialize code for type parameters of Array and List types, but they had to use hacks to get around it.

Comment: FWIW -- in response to, "Ask yourself: what happens if someone uses a T that you haven't accounted for?", that's simple, and I would think obvious --> you do appropriate validation of the generic in your constructor(s) and throw an exception if someone tries to pass off one that you don't explicitly support. Why wouldn't you *ALWAYS* do that on ANY generic class for *EXACTLY* this reason? 

Answer (score 7):

#### C# `switch` statement on a generic type argument, *i.e.* `<T>`

---

**0.** Demonstration types used in the code below.

```
class MyClass { };    struct MyStruct { };    enum MyEnum { };
```

**1.** Globally in your project, define a `struct` with a single generic type argument as follows.

```
public struct TokenOf<X> { };
```

**3.**  `switch` statement. This demo shows a generic *method*, but of course the technique can also be used anywhere within the scope of a generic `class` or `struct`: (Note that this method uses [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) syntax available in **C# 8**):

```
string GenericMethod<T>() =>
    default(TokenOf<T>) switch
    {
        TokenOf<int> _      /**/ => "II",
        TokenOf<Guid> _     /**/ => "GG",
        TokenOf<string> _   /**/ => "SS",
        TokenOf<object> _   /**/ => "OO",
        TokenOf<MyEnum> _   /**/ => "EE",
        TokenOf<MyClass> _  /**/ => "CC",
        TokenOf<MyStruct> _ /**/ => "QQ",
        _                   /**/ => "??",
    };
```

> **3a.** In these switch expression examples, you can use `{ }` instead of the "discard symbol" `_` for equivalent results. This suggests cute (or perhaps abusive) code formatting options such as:
>
> ```
> string GenericMethod<T>() => default(TokenOf<T>) switch
> {
>     TokenOf<int>      /**/ _ => "II",
>     TokenOf<Guid>     /**/ _ => "GG",
>     // etc...
>     TokenOf<MyStruct> /**/ _ => "QQ",
>     {                 /**/ } => "??",
> };
> ```

**4.** Demonstration test code

```
void switch_on_generic_type() =>
    Console.WriteLine($@"{
        GenericMethod<int>()}   {
        GenericMethod<Guid>()}   {
        GenericMethod<string>()}   {
        GenericMethod<object>()}   {
        GenericMethod<MyEnum>()}   {
        GenericMethod<MyClass>()}   {
        GenericMethod<MyStruct>()}   {
        GenericMethod<double>()}");
    }
```

**5.** Output of the demo

`II   GG   SS   OO   EE   CC   QQ   ??`

**6.** Discussion

This technique takes advantage of the fact that a .NET value-type can never not-be instantiated. It follows that value-types (unlike as with reference types--which for example lose their `System.Type` identity if `null` is stored in an underspecified variable) can never lose their specific identity. Therefore, the `TokenOf<>` struct is guaranteed to represent a different `System.Type` identity for each different parameterization by `X`, even when all are always "default" instances (which are actually 1-byte  in size). The generic type argument of the `struct` is necessary and sufficient to differentiate them.

To be clear, note that while `TokenOf<>` therefore *must* be a `struct`, the switched-upon generic type argument `<X>` can be any valid .NET type. And in fact, if `X` is guaranteed to represent a value-type, ***you don't even need the `TokenOf<>` wrapper at all***. For example, consider a generic class or method with a type argument `T` constrained by the `unmanaged` (or `struct`) keyword. In this case, an example such as (3.) from above would reduce to this:

```
string GenericMethod<T>() where T : unmanaged =>
    default(T) switch
    {
        int _      /**/ => "II",
        Guid _     /**/ => "GG",
        MyEnum _   /**/ => "EE",
        MyStruct _ /**/ => "QQ",
        TimeSpan _ /**/ => "TS",
        _          /**/ => "??",
    };
```

The `typeof(T)` operator is used in other answers on this page, but because it (by definition) manifests a [reification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_(computer_science)#Reflective_programming_languages) operation on `T` that's both inherently opaque to static analysis, and existentially hard-blocked on a [`System.Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=netframework-4.8) instance (which itself, obviously, can only exist at runtime) I consider it to be a pretty blunt and dramatic tool.

By avoiding `typeof`, the technique shown here may be friendlier to compilers, optimizers, analyzers, and other [CTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Type_System) [offline-metadata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata_(CLI)) systems (pending investigation). Most-importantly, a CIL regime which is relaxed of excessive forcible `System.Type` instantiations (via `typeof`) may prove favorable to the JIT.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bad design, because generic methods are supposed to be *generic*.

In case you really need it though, you can use pattern matching to make the code concise --

```
switch (response)
{
    case QuoteResponse q:
        // do something
    case CommitResponse ct:
        // do something else
    ...
}
```

Comment: … that’s also not generic?